# How to pass an object to an event handler in c#?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock authorText = new TextBlock();
        authorText.Text = "Saturday Morning";
        authorText.FontSize = 12;
        authorText.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        authorText.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(test1);
        authorText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        Grid.SetColumn(authorText, 0);

        sp_s.Children.Add(authorText);
    }


void sampleDropDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I want to be able to access authorText object inside sampleDropDown event handler.
 Moving the object declaration outside the scope of Button_Click method is not a valid solution, as I need to create a new object with every click of a button.

Comment: Usually `RoutedEventArgs` are extended for such cases, but there is no harm in declaring as instance variable (at least in this case).  Also I don't see `sampleDropDown` been called _explicitly_ in your case, I would suggest making class variable for such cases.

Comment: What is `sampleDropDown` a handler for, and where is it assigned?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a new object with every click of a button

If you genuinely need a new object, you can still hold a reference to each object in a collection at the class level. Then, in each `Button_Click` handler create a new object and add it to the list.

```
List<TextBlock> authorTextList = new List<TextBlock>();

public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock authorText = new TextBlock();
    authorTextList.Add(authorText);

    /// ...
}

void sampleDropDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /// ... access List objects here as desired
}
```

But it looks like you may already have a list of your authorText objects:

```
sp_s.Children.Add(authorText);
```

A reference to `authorText` is held in `sp_s.Children`.  Unless the reference is removed before you need it in the `sampleDropDown()` handler, you can probably access it there.